# MultipleChoiceFilter to Checkboxes

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a ModelMultipleChoiceFilter working, however I cant find a way to adjust it from a input multiple choice to a checkbox list.

**This is what I currently have:**

[image: What I currently have]

**This is what I want to convert it to:**

[image]

My current code:

```
class GameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

gamemodes = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=GameMode.objects.all(),
        label='Game modes (or)',
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the keyword argument `widget` with [`CheckboxSelectMultiple` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple) to your filter:

```
from django import forms

class GameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    gamemodes = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=GameMode.objects.all(),
        label='Game modes (or)',
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
```

Comment: aha, I can use django forms widgets! Thanks!